# What is ABA and BAB schemes when talking about numerical integrators

Tags: ode, terminology

I have read a lot about numerical integrators (ode solvers) lately and tried reading a few papers but I have stumbled upon something that I can't understand and it's something called ABA and BAB.

For example in this paper [New families of symplectic splitting methods for numerical integration in dynamical astronomy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0689.pdf) they have tables with coefficients but I haven't figured out how to interpret those and code an algorithm with them because I haven't found what ABA and BAB schemes are, Google isn't helping me a lot sadly. How are those tables meant to be interpreted?

Comment: It looks like they are introduced in equation 5. It seems they define sampling points relative to the timestep size for a splitting of the solution (indexed by a and b)?

Comment: Seems like there was a lot more to it than I thought . Do you know anywhere I could read up on those things?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out Section 3 in chapter III of:

E. Hairer, C. Lubich, and G. Wanner, Geometric numerical integration: structure-preserving algorithms for ordinary differential equations, Second., vol. 31. Berlin: Springer-Verlag, 2006.

and/or:

[A. Murua, “The Hopf Algebra of Rooted Trees, Free Lie Algebras, and Lie Series,” Foundations of Computational Mathematics, vol. 6, no. 4, pp. 387–426, Nov. 2006.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.560.2136&rep=rep1&type=pdf)